# Unable to install flutter_typeahead v1.8.5

Tags: flutter, installation, get, version, typeahead

[image: Screenshot showing error]

I get the following error:

```
pub get failed (1; Because pharmacyapp depends on flutter_keyboard_visibility >=3.0.0 which requires Flutter SDK version >=1.12.13+hotfix.6 <2.0.0, version solving failed.)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think upgrading your flutter SDK version should solve the problem .
Go to command prompt and run the command

`flutter upgrade`

It will update the flutter to the latest version.

Comment: @Bencheikh Rokia  did it work for you ? If so , please accept the answer

Comment: yes it works for me ... excuse me i am new in stack Overflow thanks

Answer (score 0):

Either you upgrade the flutter to 1.12.13+hotfix.6 or more. Or degrade flutter_keyboard_visibility which supports the flutter version that you have installed.

You can use fvm (https://pub.dev/packages/fvm) to manage your flutter version. It can be specific to a project also.